# pip install in google deep learning vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pip, google-compute-engine

I'm using one of the deep leaning images but am really only familiar with installing packages using conda which appears to not be used in the image. How do I pip install a package to my jupyter notebook kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install python packages from Jupyter Kernel like this:

```
# Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
```

You can have a look at [this document](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/) for more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks, I got there on my own in the end. Do you know how to access the python environment in the terminal? I couldn't get that working.

Comment: You can read more about virtual environment's [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for python 3 or [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215489338-Installing-and-using-virtualenv-with-Python-2) for python 2.